# How to fix 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received' chrome issue?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using VueJS and Laravel for my project. This issue started to show lately and it shows even in the old git branches.

This error only shows in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Do you have any ad blocker ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914490/how-to-handle-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-res perhaps the answer here is more beneficial than simply 'disable x extension'

Answer (score 519, accepted):

I disabled all installed extensions in Chrome - works for me.
I have now clear console without errors.

Comment: How is disabling all extensions a solution... or even a consideration. For many of us the extensions provide essential functionality.

Comment: Disabling or toggling extensions that are listening to browser interactions may cause this, i.e.   WebRecorders, API Assistants (Amazon..) and others that are constantly waiting for interaction...

Comment: how to find errors caused by which extension?

Answer (score 283):

In case you're an extension developer who googled your way here trying to stop causing this error:

The issue isn't CORB (as another answer here states)  as blocked CORs [manifest as warnings](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers) like -

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
> https://www.example.com/example.html with MIME type text/html. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
> details.

The issue is most likely a mishandled async response to runtime.sendMessage.  As [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage):

> To send an asynchronous response, there are two options:
>
> - return true from the event listener. This keeps the sendResponse
>   function valid after the listener returns, so you can call it later.
> - return a Promise from the event listener, and resolve
>   when you have the response (or reject it in case of an error).

When you send an async response but fail to use either of these mechanisms, the supplied `sendResponse` argument to `sendMessage` goes out of scope and the result is exactly as the error message says: your message port (the message-passing apparatus) is closed before the response was received.

Webextension-polyfill authors have [already written about it in June 2018](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/130).

So bottom line, if you see your extension causing these errors - inspect closely all your onMessage listeners. Some of them probably need to start returning promises <s>(marking them as async should be enough).</s> [Thanks @vdegenne]

Comment: As an heads up don't use `async/await` for your background listener callback. This is what failed for me, I removed `async` and transformed my `await` structure in a `then` structure code and now it works.

Comment: but... i'm not trying to send any response, nor am I expecting one!

Comment: What a great fix, thanks!  All I had to do is add `return true;` at the bottom of my _chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()_ function and the problem was solved!  I am using jQuery's `$.ajax` inside this function which is why I need this fix.

Comment: @vdegenne you can use `async` for the listener, but then you can't `return true` at the end, and can't use the `sendResponse` callback. You just have to resolve **with** the actual response.

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to return true from the callback in chrome.tabs.executeScript, which was inside a listener.

Comment: Just calling sendResponse({}) within a (non-async) addListener callback worked for me (no need to return true, and just returning true didn't work for me)

Comment: @Michael In Chrome v99+ extensions, this is a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71520198/2336725

Comment: @Teepeemm Curiously, I'm getting the same issue in Chrome 101 with a Manifest V2 extension. At least it should be fixed in 102.

Comment: @vdegenne thanks, your comment fixed my issue. But I don't understand why async/await doesn't work. I thought it would be the same thing?

Comment: @Papooch what do you mean you can use await but without sendResponse? How do you actually control what data to return?

Comment: @Andy if you use `async`, then a Promise gets returned implicitly. That means the second bullet point applies and the async function (the promise) should return the actual data and _not_ `true`.

Answer (score 88):

If you go to [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/), you can just toggle each extension one at a time and see which one is actually triggering the issue.

Once you toggle the extension off, refresh the page where you are seeing the error and wiggle the mouse around, or click. Mouse actions are the things that are throwing errors.

So I was able to pinpoint which extension was actually causing the issue and disable it.

Answer (score 62):

I had same problem when responding on message in callback. The solution is to return **true** in background message listener.

Here is simple example of **background.js**. It responses to any message from popup.js.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(rq, sender, sendResponse) {
    // setTimeout to simulate any callback (even from storage.sync)
    setTimeout(function() {
        sendResponse({status: true});
    }, 1);
    // return true;  // uncomment this line to fix error
});
```

Here is **popup.js**, which sends message on popup. You'll get exceptions until you un-comment "return true" line in **background.js** file.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "ping"}, function(resp) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    });
});
```

**manifest.json**, just in case :) Pay attention on alarm permissions section!

```
{
  "name": "TestMessages",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "src/popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "alarms"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It worked for me! What scenario the default `return false` would be useful?

Comment: [Docs says](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage): `This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true`. What means invalid? doesn't it suppose to be created every time it receives a message anyways?

Comment: @EduardoReis, with FALSE it could be used as informer to notify about some event.

Comment: Aleksej, Can you help me how to include addListener code in struts 1 web project . i use JS, JSP,HTML , FRAMES, CSS as UI stack. just wondered where exactly need to apply it. tried added below snippet in parent js file but it doesn't recognize. usually i dont have listener code in my app. chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(rq, sender, sendResponse) { setTimeout(function() { sendResponse({status: true}); }, 1); alert("Inside Background.js file"); return true; // Return true to fix the error });

Comment: Sorry, I don't know JSP to help you with. Did you locate listener in your JS code?

Answer (score 43):

I was using a VPN extension called Free VPN for Chrome - VPN Proxy VeePN. It was causing the error; after disabling it the error disappeared

Comment: This repeats the accepted answer from 3 years prior and should be deleted.

Comment: The accepted answer says "Disable all extensions", so no, this is no the same as the accepted answer. This answer is actually useful, and has worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

This error is generally caused by one of your Chrome extensions.

I recommend installing this [One-Click Extension Disabler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-extensions-tempor/lcfdefmogcogicollfebhgjiiakbjdje), I use it with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>COMMAND (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT (⇧)</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> — to quickly disable/enable all my extensions.

Once the extensions are disabled this error message should go away.

Comment: ctrl+shit+d - don't work in linux, and no hotkeys for this extension. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-extensions-tempor/lcfdefmogcogicollfebhgjiiakbjdje

And tanks for this extension.

Comment: This repeats the accepted answer from a year prior and should be deleted.

Answer (score 10):

If error reason is extension use incognito  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. In incognito mode Chrome does not have extensions.

**UPD.** If you need some extension in incognito mode e.g. ReduxDevTools or any other, in extension settings turn on "Allow in incognito"

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are using the correct syntax.

We should use the **sendMessage()** method after listening it.

Here is a simple example of **contentScript.js** It sendRequest to **app.js**.

**contentScript.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    title: 'giveSomeTitle', params: paramsToSend
  }, function(result) { 
    // Do Some action
});
```

**app.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener( function(message, sender, 
 sendResponse) {
  if(message.title === 'giveSomeTitle'){
    // Do some action with message.params
    sendResponse(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: `sendRequest`  is deprecated use `sendMessage`

Answer (score 4):

For those coming here to debug this error in Chrome 73, one possibility is because Chrome 73 onwards disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts.

More reading:

1. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768
2. https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches

This affects many Chrome extension authors, who now need to scramble to fix the extensions because Chrome thinks "Our data shows that most extensions will not be affected by this change."

(it has nothing to do with your app code)

**UPDATE**: I fixed the CORs issue but I still see this error. I suspect it is Chrome's fault here.

Comment: This answer does not address the question, by its own admission, and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a breakpoint set in my own page source.  If I removed or disabled the breakpoint then the error would clear up.

The breakpoint was in a moderately complex chunk of rendering code.  Other breakpoints in different parts of the page had no such effect.  I was not able to work out a simple test case that always trigger this error.