# Trying to fetch data from an api using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'am trying to fetch data from a online MongoDb database using javascript and html. but it doesn't work properly. Also using jquery library too

```html
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="GET DATA FROM API" id="getAPI">
    <div id="result" ></div>
    <div ><h2>Input Form</h2></div>
    <form id="postData" >
    </form>
</div>
<!-- javascript part -->
<script>
    document.getElementById('getAPI').addEventListener('click', getAPI);
    function getAPI() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/seller')
            .then((res) => { return res.json() })
            .then((data) => {
                let result = `<h2> Random User Info From Jsonplaceholder API</h2>`;
                data.forEach((seller) => {
                    const {id, name, email} = seller
                    result +=
                        `<div>
                                <h5> User ID: ${id} </h5>
                                <ul>
                                    <li> User Full Name : ${name}</li>
                                    <li> User Email : ${email} </li>
                                </ul>
                             </div>`;
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
                });
            })
    }
</script>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't give any result as a output

Comment: Does it make the ajax request? Is there a JSON response?

Comment: this can be seen in the chrome console                                                                                             
                                                                                                            
                                                                                                            
view.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
view.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: now this                                                                           view.html?_ijt=72t9n4ls8vjcs5g7minkkcai31:28 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    let result = `<h2> Random User Info From Jsonplaceholder API</h2>`;
    data.forEach(seller => {
      const {
        id,
        name,
        email
      } = seller;
      result += `<div>
                   <h5> User ID: ${id} </h5>
                   <ul>
                     <li> User Full Name : ${name}</li>
                     <li> User Email : ${email} </li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>`;
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = result;
    });
  });
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Your Front End works well. I replaced the api url in your code and everything is fine. It might be something on the Back End. Did you check the status code that you get from the server?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, but I can't execute code example inside the comments and by the code example, there is nothing to change on the FE side.

Comment: I checked the api using postman and it worked fine. Is that okay ?

Comment: Im seeing thin in chrome console                                                              
                                                                                                                   
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
8Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Can you open network tab in the chrome dev tools? Here you can check more info about response from the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon Check out these solutions and see if might help you.

Comment: Request URL: https://cr-input.mxpnl.net/data?_channel_id=&_partner_id=39571&_sub_id=0000&_app_version=1.0.23&_app=cs-dca
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 52.72.99.240:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: good idea. i checked and above comment is what I saw. sure I will check

Comment: opend the page using incognito. and received following in chrome console                         view.html?_ijt=72t9n4ls8vjcs5g7minkkcai31:28 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: Hmm, check the value of the data before doing foreach. It looks like data is not an array, maybe it's an object? You can check it with console.log(data);

Comment: aaah since Im using MongoDb it saves data as an object . So that might be the issue here ?