# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) failed to resolve error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello Im facing this issue, whenever I access deployed url, It gives me blank page and this error 404

[image]

And then reloading again it gives that page, it shows me no blank page

Im using,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js" async></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I can't recognise issue.
Thanks in advance, it would be great if somebody help.

Comment: that's a back end problem,  something with your server, not your front end build

Comment: @poPaTheGuru Ooh, but errors such as 404 is a client side error
If it is a server error, it should give something like 500

Comment: who says 404 error is a client error ? its a backend error and it says the page is not defined or cannot be found in the backend code. whatever. you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon)

Comment: The Url you are looking for is not found, so plz update and double check the Url

Comment: what do you use for your backend?

Comment: @poPaTheGuru django

Comment: @user16398638 i asked hoping you might use node.js and could help you somehow, but i have no idea about django
Sorry. good look with your problem