# populate 2nd drop down based on 1st drop down result by using ajax in codeigniter php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to do the 2nd drop down population based on the 1st drop down by using ajax in codeigniter. But my problem is after I choose for 1st drop down value, when I try to choose for 2nd drop down value, it shows empty only.

(Update: I already fixed my problem. So, I already updated my code.)

Image below shows that the result after I choose for 1st option. When I try to select for 2nd option, it can't shows the value:
[image: Here is the problem that I'm facing]

Here's is the code for view:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-center"><?php echo $content_heading;?></h3>
                    <form action="#" id="form" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="subject_name">Subject Name</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="subject_name" id="subject_name">
                                   <option>-- Select Subject Name --</option>
                                   <?php foreach($attendance as $row){
                                     echo "<option value='".$row['subject_id']."'>".$row['subject_name']."</option>";
                                   }
                                   ?>
                                </select>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lecturer_name">Lecturer Name</label>
                                    <input name="lecturer_name" placeholder="Lecturer Name" class="form-control" type="text" disabled="">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subject_section">Section</label>
                                     <select  class="form-control" name = "subject_section" id='subject_section'>
                                       <option>-- Select Subject Section --</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="attendance_date">Date</label>
                                    <input name="attendance_date" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" type="date">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="attendance_start_time">From</label>
                                    <input name="attendance_start_time" placeholder="From" class="form-control" type="time">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="attendance_end_time">To</label>
                                    <input name="attendance_end_time" placeholder="To" class="form-control" type="time">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                                </div>
                        <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="save()">Confirm</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript for the ajax function. (I already updated my javascript code.)

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 
    // Subject change
    $('#subject_name').change(function(){
      var subject_id = $(this).val();

      // AJAX request
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('attendance/get_subject_section')?>",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {subject_id: subject_id},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){

          // Remove options 
          $('#subjectsection').find('option').not(':first').remove();

          // Add options
          $.each(response,function(index,data){
             $('#subject_section').append('<option value="'+data['subject_id']+'">'+data['subject_section']+'</option>');
          });
        }
     });
   }); 
 });
</script>
```

Here is the code for controller:

```
    <?php class attendance extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Attendance Data/attendance_model','attendance');
}

function index(){
    //$this->load->view('Manage User Registration/user_login_view');
    $data['meta_title'] = 'Attendance';
    $data['content_heading'] = 'Attendance';
    $data['main_content'] = 'Manage Student Attendance/attendance';
    $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');

    if($this->session->userdata('user_type')==='lecturer'){
        $data['user_type'] = 'lecturer';
        $data['meta_user_level_title'] = 'Lecturer';
        $data['id'] = $this->session->id;
        $data['main_content'] = 'Manage Student Attendance/lecturer_attendance_view';
        $this->load->view('template/template', $data);
    }else{
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
}

    public function create_attendance()
{
    $data['meta_title'] = 'Add Subject Attendance';
    $data['content_heading'] = 'Add Subject Attendance';
    $data['main_content'] = 'Manage Student Attendance/attendance';
    $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['user_type'] = 'lecturer';
    $data['heading'] = 'Lecturer';

    if($this->session->userdata('user_type')==='lecturer'){
        $data['user_type'] = 'lecturer';
        $data['attendance'] = $this->attendance->get_subject_name();
        $data['meta_user_level_title'] = 'Lecturer';
        $data['id'] = $this->session->id;
        $data['main_content'] = 'Manage Student Attendance/create_attendance';
        $this->load->view('template/template', $data);
    }else{
        echo "Access Denied";
    }
}

    public function get_subject_section()
{ 
    // POST data 
    $subject_id= $this->input->post('subject_id');
    
    // get data 
    $data = $this->attendance->get_subject_section($subject_id);
    echo json_encode($data); 
}}
```

Here is my code for model:

```
<?php class attendance_model extends CI_Model{

    //Get subject name
    public function get_subject_name()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata("id");
    $response = array();
 
    // Select record
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('lecturer_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->group_by('subject_id');
    $query = $this->db->get('lecturer_timetable');
    $response = $query->result_array();

    return $response;
}

    //Get subject section
    public function get_subject_section($subject_id){
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata("id");
        $response = array();
     
        // Select record
        $this->db->select('subject_id, subject_section');
        $this->db->where('lecturer_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('subject_id', $subject_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('lecturer_timetable');
        $response = $query->result_array();

        return $response;
    }}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url in ajax is unreadable because of quotation. Try to writer in proper quotation. Use either single quotes inside double quotes or use double inside single. Second is, you are using method as 'POST' but in lowercase. Write POST in uppercase.

```
$.ajax({    
    url : "<?php echo site_url('attendance/get_subject_section')?>",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {subject_name: subject_name},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){        
        console.log(response); // first check by console that you are getting records in response. once you get response then append it or do whatever you want
    
    }

});
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I already changed based on what you wrote, but it still having the same problem.

Comment: can you please share an image or show your reponse in devtool?

Comment: Hi, i already shared the picture, kindly have a look. Thank you.

Comment: please disabled all installed extensions in browser if you have and then gradually examine which extension makes you in trouble. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon)

Comment: Hi, I already removed the extension and update the picture again, thank you.

Comment: please share again your code

Comment: Hi, I already updated my ajax code, other than that is still the same. Thank you.

Comment: check your this.value by alert before the ajax call. And also verify either  you have data against particular option

Comment: ok, sir it already worked after i used alert to check the data it pass to controller. I didn't realize that I suppose pass the id instead of subject name. Thank you sir for your helping.