# multiple dependent dropdown in add page and edit page in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I need to add multiple dropdowns to my project and it also needs a dependent multiple dropdowns

The existing dropdown category should be changed to multiple dropdowns
Automatically they select values in its dependent subcategory multiple dropdowns it its possible ?

Current Single Choice Dependent Dropdown How To Make Multiple Choose Dependent Dropdown?

please help me

```
view page

 
                        <label for="category_id"><?php echo get_phrase('category'); ?> <span
                                class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="category_id" id="category_id" required multiple>
                            <option value="" hidden><?php echo get_phrase('select category'); ?></option>
                            <?php
                                                            $roles = $this->db->get('category_table')->result_array();
                                                            foreach($roles as $row):
                                                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>">
                                <?php echo $row['category_name'];?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                                                            endforeach;
                                                        ?>
                        </select>
              
                        <label for="idsubcategory"><?php echo get_phrase('Sub_category'); ?>
                            <span class="text-danger"></span> </label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="idsubcategory" id="idsubcategory"
                            placeholder="subcategory" multiple>
                            <option value="" hidden><?php echo get_phrase('select subcategory'); ?></option>
                            <?php
                                                            $roles = $this->db->get('sub_category')->result_array();
                                                            foreach($roles as $row):
                                                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['idsubcategory'];?>">
                                <?php echo $row['subcategory_name'];?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                                                            endforeach;
                                                        ?>
                        </select>
```

ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
   {
  $('#category_id').change(function() {
    var category_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/get_sub_category');?>",
        method: "POST",

        data: {
            category_id: category_id
        },
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value=' + data[i].idsubcategory + '>' + data[i]
                    .subcategory_name + '</option>';
            }
            $('#idsubcategory').html(html);

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

controller

```
  function get_sub_category(){

       $category_id = $this->input->post('category_id',TRUE);

       $data = $this->Crud_model->get_sub_category($category_id)->result();

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

model

```
    function get_sub_category($category_id){

    $query = $this->db->get_where('sub_category', array('category_id' => $category_id));

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select1">
     <option value='opt1'>Option 1</option>
     <option value='opt2'>Option 2</option>
     <option value='opt3'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
<select>


<select id="select3">
<select>


<script>

$('#select1').change(function() {
    var category_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/function_for_second_dropdown');?>",
        method: "POST",

        data: {
            category_id: category_id
        },
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value=' + data[i].idsubcategory + '>' + data[i].your_option+ '</option>';
            }
            $('#select2').append(html);

        }
    });

$('#select2').change(function() {
    var select2= $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/function_for_third_dropdown');?>",
        method: "POST",

        data: {
            select2: select2
        },
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += '<option value=' + data[i].your_option + '>' + data[i].your_option+ '</option>';
            }
            $('#select2').append(html);

        }
    });




</script>
```

Comment: I just selected a value in the category dropdown and then its dependent value came up in the subcategory dropdown and then I selected the next value as multiple in the category dropdown.
  Then the subcategory dropdown should show the dependent subcategory values of both the categories. is possible ?

Comment: what you want? Do you want to get data which reflects by second selected option?

Comment: i want add multiple dependent dropdown now its only work single data showing in subcategory dropdown i need multiple display multiple data

Comment: like this                                                                                    
                                                                                         
       https://phppot.com/demo/load-dependent-dropdown-on-multi-select-using-php-and-jquery/

Comment: please visit this link too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69884612/populate-2nd-drop-down-based-on-1st-drop-down-result-by-using-ajax-in-codeignite/69885935#69885935