# Javascript send message from content.js to background.js

Tags: javascript

I read some of the chrome docs and got [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#simple) basic example working.

Now I want to make the request based on an event happening. The event is triggered and contentUpdateData() runs, but the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` within the function doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why?

```
/* content.js */ 
var data = []

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sesnder, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === 'popupClicked') {
            contentUpdateData();
        }
    }
)

function contentUpdateData() {
    console.log('Code works up to here. Button clicked in popup.html, recieved in content.js. Need to get info from background.js')
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
        data = response.data
      });
}
```

```
/* background.js basic example from chrome */ 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting === "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye", data: null});
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return true` from the event listener in backgroundjs. This saves `sendResponse()` from [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483156).

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.greeting === "hello") sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye", data: null });
  // VERY IMPORTANT
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the background.js did not sync properly after updating the extension. This was the cause for the error.