# React error on onclick event and function handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react code

```
const MenuItem = ({title, imageUrl, linkUrl}) => {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () =>{
        setIsClicked(true);
    }

    const handleLocation = () => {
        if(window.location.pathname === '/movie'){  
            <MoviePage categoryId={linkUrl}/>
        }
    }

    return ( 
            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="image-container" style={{backgroundImage:`url(${imageUrl})`}}/>
                    <div className="image-content"
                        onClick={handleClick}>
                        {isClicked ? {handleLocation}: null}
                        <h1>{title}</h1>
                </div> 
            </div>
    );
}
```

Here, on the onclick event I want to render the component on another page, so I used window.location, but getting this error

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {handleLocation}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: `handleLocation` is a function and you are trying to render that, not a component.

Comment: `{isClicked ? {handleLocation}: null}` should be `{isClicked ? handleLocation() : null}`. The `{`/`}` before `isClicked` and after `null` will change the context from JSX to JavaScript. `{handleLocation}` in plain JavaScript is simply a shortcut for `{ handleLocation: handleLocation }`. Since objects cannot be rendered by JSX this produces an error. You probably meant to call the function. Do note that `handleLocation` should also be updated to return a value. It currently never returns anything, so even with the error solved `<MoviePage>` will never be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you would navigate in a React app - you need a routing solution, for example https://reactrouter.com/

With react-router you can define and configure your routes and navigate to them without reloading the page.

Try to work you through the tutorial: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Basically, you would have a router with routes like this:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="expenses" element={<Expenses />} />
      <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I know I should use react-router, but now I want to navigate with window.location. Can you please help me with the error

Comment: is there any reason?

Answer (score 0):

From [offical document](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html),

> You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX.

> JSX is an Expression Too
> After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript function calls and evaluate to JavaScript objects.

```
<div
  className="image-content"
  onClick={handleClick}
>
    {isClicked ? {handleLocation} : null} // should be {isClicked ? handleLocation() : null}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
</div>
```

In your code, `handleLocation` with curly braces will be the **Javascript expression** by JSX grammer. So `{handleLocation}` will be a reference of your function `handleLocation`. It is never **called**. You should make it called like `handleLocation()`.

```
const handleLocation = () => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/movie') {  
    <MoviePage categoryId={linkUrl}/> // it is just a expression, not returns any value
  }
}
```

One more change you need in your code is to return **JSX** element in `handleLocation`. `<MoviePage />` in the if statement is just a expression. So this function whill never return any value. You should add `return` in front of `<MoviePage />`, then ReactDOM will render this component.

```
return <MoviePage categoryId={linkUrl} />
```

Comment: It is giving me this error  Uncaught (in promise) Error: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: @Vasanti Suthar [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon)

Comment: Okay, so now the error is gone, but it is not navigating to the new page