# Recorded Big Blue Button video sessions coming out not showing the document presented

Tags: ubuntu, moodle, bigbluebutton

I have installed Moodle 4.0 and it came with BBB plugin pre-installed freely hosted by Blindside networks. When I do live session on Big Blue Button I record and when I view recordings it does not show the document which was presented there will be a black overlay on top of it. see screenshot

Please assist.....[screenshot of the recorded session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvOXd.png)

Comment: Couple of suggestions - maybe try using a different theme to see if its a theme fault, Site admin > Appearance > Themes > Theme selector - also try viewing the developer console, then refresh the page to see if there are any errors - in Chrome menu > More tools > Developer tools - also try different browsers to see if its browser specific

Comment: Hi Russel, I have changed the theme and tried another browser but still getting the same thing, Please Mind the black overlay is on the document in particular not all of the presentation. When I open the developer tools this is the error I am getting:: 
                                               "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
VM9:86 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firefoxSample')
    at eval (eval at buildCode (recordings.rna1.blindsidenetworks.com/:606:31), <anonymous>:86:1151467)*

Comment: Could possibly be a browser extension - try turning them off, especially virus checkers and ad blockers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon

Comment: Hi, I have managed to remove extension, its now okay ,Thanks a lot though the other device its refusing but will try to win it as well

Comment: Oh cool, which browser extension was it?

Comment: it was savefromnet.com