# I get the errors: Warning: Invalid hook call and error Unchecked runtime.lastError:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, error-handling

The vs code compiler does not give an error(webpack compiled successfully) only the console in the browser gives me an error:

I get the error:
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
react.development.js:209

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <styled.nav> component:

at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78041:8)
at Navbar
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66643:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:64758:5)
at div
at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useDebugValue')
    at useDebugValue (react.development.js:1659:1)
    at StyledComponent.js:116:1
    at O (StyledComponent.js:174:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import About from "./pages/about";
import Contact from "./pages/contact";
import Projects from "./pages/projects";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" Component={About}></Route>
        <Route path="/projects" Component={Projects}></Route>
        <Route path="/contact" Component={Contact}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is the package Json file

```
{
  "name": "mi_portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
  
}
```

also there is no repeat version of react using npm ls react :

```
C:\Users\PERSONAL\AppData\Roaming\npm
├─┬ react-router-dom@6.16.0
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-router@6.16.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0
└─┬ styled-components@5.3.10
  ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  └── react@18.2.0
```

I don't know where the issue is with this code I have tried a lot of things like adding the peer dependencies but did not work out I think I have some typo:

Navbar component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Nav, NavMenu, NavLink, Bars } from "./NavbarElements";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Bars />
      <NavMenu>
        <NavLink to="/about" activeStyle>
          About
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/projects" activeStyle>
          Projects
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/contact" activeStyle>
          Contact
        </NavLink>
      </NavMenu>
    </Nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

NavbarElements file:

```
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
import { NavLink as Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #63d471;
  height: 85px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.2rem calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);
  z-index: 12;
  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-start; */
`;

export const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #808080;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  &.active {
    color: #000000;
  }
`;

export const Bars = styled(FaBars)`
  display: none;
  color: #808080;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 75%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: -24px;
  /* Second Nav */
  /* margin-right: 24px; */
  /* Third Nav */
  /* width: 100vw; 
white-space: nowrap; */
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

about component:

```
import React from "react";

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Comment: You need to post the code causing the issue.  (Hint:  It's probably in NavBar like the error says)

Comment: @possum I am not using hooks I think the error is in the import of Routes

Comment: @possum already upload the file,

Comment: If you drop `NavBar` out does the problem shift elsewhere?

Comment: @possum without Navbar I only get:                                                                                 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
localhost/:30 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
localhost/:30 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
localhost/:30 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: You've got something weird going on to be sure.  That last error has a thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon  Got any weird chrome extensions?

Comment: If you disable them or fire up a different browser without any extensions does it behave differently?

Comment: @possum I got the same output error without extensions and in bing

Comment: bing isn't a browser

Comment: @Konrad sorry, I was referring to edge

Comment: The thing is that vs code compiler does not give any errors(webpack compiled successfully) is only the console in the browser that does not render anything and gets me the errors

Comment: You don't have `/` route. Did you try to go to `/about`?

Comment: @Konrad I update the  question About seems to be fine

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useDebugValue')